# Create sample value for failure records spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a scenario where my dataframe has 3 columns a,b and c. I need to validate if the length of all the columns is equal to 100. Based on validation I am creating status column like a_status,b_status,c_status with values 5 (Success) and 10 (Failure). In Failure scenarios I need to update count and create new columns a_sample,b_sample,c_sample with some 5 failure sample values separated by ",". For creating samples column I tried like this

```
df= df.select(df.columns.toList.map(col(_)) ::: 
         df.columns.toList.map( x => (lit(getSample(df.select(x, x + "_status").filter(x + "_status=10" ).select(x).take(5))).alias(x + "_sample")) ).toList: _* )
```

getSample method will just get array of rows and concatenate as a string. This works fine for limited columns and data size. However if the number of columns > 200 and data is > 1 million rows it creates huge performance impact. Is there any alternate approach for same.

Comment: So do you need to aggregate all failed records and take a sample? And then concat 5 fields in a column? It's all very unclear. Maybe some more code will help me understand the underlying logic.

Answer (score 0):

While the details of your problem statement are unclear, you can break up the task into two parts:

1. Transform data into a format where you identify several different types of rows you need to sample.
2. Collect sample by row type.

The industry jargon for "row type" is stratum/strata and the way to do (2), without collecting data to the driver, which you don't want to do when the data is large, is via stratified sampling, which Spark implements via `df.stat.sampleBy()`. As a statistical function, it doesn't work with exact row numbers but fractions. If you absolutely must get a sample with an exact number of rows there are two strategies:

- Oversample by fraction and then filter unneeded rows, e.g., using the `row_number()` window function followed by a filter `'row_num < n`.
- Build a custom user-defined aggregate function (UDAF), `firstN(col, n)`. This will be much faster but a lot more work. See https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html

An additional challenge for your use case is that you want this done per column. This is not a good fit with Spark's transformations such as grouping or `sampleBy`, which operate on rows. The simple approach is to make several passes through the data, one column at a time. If you absolutely must do this in a single pass through the data, you'll need to build a much more custom UDAF or `Aggregator`, e.g., the equivalent of `takeFirstNFromAWhereBHasValueC(n, colA, colB, c)`.